# Dygraphs - Combine candlestick with other line series

Tags: dygraphs, candlestick-chart

I am trying to create a multi-series chart which include a candlestick plot.

Using the example in http://dygraphs.com/tests/plotters.html, I've passed in the OHLC array and made the following changes: -

```
var sets = e.points;
for (var p = 0 ; p < sets.length; p++) {
    price = {
        open : sets[p].yval[0],
        close : sets[p].yval[1],
        high : sets[p].yval[2],
        low : sets[p].yval[3],
        openY :  ???  
        closeY : ???
        highY : ???
        lowY : ???
    };
    prices.push(price);
}
```

How do I get the y values? I've tried both: -

```
openY: e.dygraph.toDomYCoord(points[p].yval[0]) 
openY: e.axis.g.toDomYCoord(points[p].yval[0])
```

but am getting a 'Cannot read property 'toPercentYCoord' of undefined' error.

What's the correct way to do this?

Thanks